# getListView().addFooterView(view) not working in Android 2.2

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

Here is the code in my `public class AnalListFragment extends ListFragment` class

```
public void addFooterLoader() {
    Parcelable state = getListView().onSaveInstanceState();

    setListAdapter(null);
    LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
    View loaderView = factory.inflate(R.layout.list_more_content_footer, null);
    getListView().addFooterView(loaderView); // EXCEPTION HERE
    setAdapterData();       

    getListView().onRestoreInstanceState(state);
}
```

Layout file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
<ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

So when I run this code on my 4.1 android device it does fine. But when I run it on 2.2 device it throws an exception:

```
 12-09 15:57:07.861: E/AndroidRuntime(10621): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-09 15:57:07.861: E/AndroidRuntime(10621): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-09 15:57:07.861: E/AndroidRuntime(10621):    at android.widget.AdapterView$AdapterDataSetObserver.onChanged(AdapterView.java:778)
12-09 15:57:07.861: E/AndroidRuntime(10621):    at android.widget.ListView.addFooterView(ListView.java:421)
12-09 15:57:07.861: E/AndroidRuntime(10621):    at android.widget.ListView.addFooterView(ListView.java:436)
12-09 15:57:07.861: E/AndroidRuntime(10621):    at com.example.analytics.AnalListFragment.addFooterLoader(AnalListFragment.java:150)
```

I have no idea what's wrong and why it doesn't work on 2.2 device.

Comment: Have you tried removing this line: `setListAdapter(null);`

Comment: Hm, I've thought It shouldn't work since documentation says "this method could only be called before setting the adapter" about `addFooterView()`. But it has helped me. Could you explain me this documentation issue please?

Comment: To be honest I've never had this problem. The answer came by its logics. When you set the adapter to null, you are saying that the listview has a null adapter and the error in your logCat shows that they have an error null in your adapterView. It means in you adapter is null; in this case, your adapter.